# Which Platform to Use For Rendering 3D Graph With 50.000 Vertices and 700.000 Edges?

Tags: graphics, 3d, visualization

We're trying to visualize a massive graph that transforms over time but we're unsure which platform would be powerful enough to do this.

We tried using Unity, but importing the 50.000 vertices was a big problem already. With static Batching we could get up to 100fps, but we want to change the vertices color depending on parameters. Therefore static Batching was not an option. We tried using other batching systems in combination with different rendering pipelines but then we could get 20 fps at most. We concluded that unity probably isn't the best platform for our purposes since there is so much stuff happening in the background.

Comment: Which graphics card are you using ?

Comment: We use gtx 1080, rtx 2080 and a laptop version of the 2060

Answer (score 0):

try doing some optimizations like

I think your problem is all about performance these is some performance tips  as i see 50K vertices are good

1. rendering only what camera see by using [Occlusion culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html)
2. Make objects that dosnt move mark as static by selecting it and check static in top right corner in inpector
3. back light instead of realtime lighting & reflections
4. try use texture map to use same material on multiple objects and select material> inspector check Enable gpu instancing

good luck !